# Child entity is null after parent entity is persisted and selected

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Please help! It has already taken me a day, and I am no closer to resolving the issue. My set up is as follows:

1. Eclipse Indigo
2. Eclipselink 2.3
3. Apache Tomcat 6

What I am doing is I am persisting an entity that has an @OneToOne mapping with a child entity. Once the record is in the database, I am running a select and successfully selecting the newly inserted record. However, the child entity is null.

My goal is to only insert the parent record, because the child record is already in the DB.

Question: what do I need to change to cause the child record to be populated?

I have an entity that I persist:

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
try {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(timeSheet);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

The entity contains @OneToOne:

```
@Entity
@Cache(expiry=-1)
@Table(name="TIME_SHEET")
    public class TimeSheet implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name="PROJECT_ID", referencedColumnName="PROJECT_ID", nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID", referencedColumnName="COMPANY_ID", nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
        })
        private Project project;
        public Project getProject() {
            return project;
        }
```

The child entity is:

```
@Entity
@Cache(expiry=-1)
@Table(name="PROJECT")
public class Project implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProjectPK id;
```

After "TimeSheet" is persisted and selected, "Project" is null. What should I do to ensure that "Project" is populated?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the code shown, you persist a TimeSheet without first setting a Project in it, so why would you expect it to have a Project when you load it? You should never expect your object model to look different after you load it than it did before you saved it. If it *does* look different, then you have a problem.

Comment: Thank you Ryan! What I intended to do is to persist TimeSheet only (Project would already be in the DB before the time TimeSheet is inserted). Then, as a different transaction, by clicking a button on a JSP the user would refresh a list of TimeSheets. But, when the list is refreshed, the Project object will be loaded in 1 minutute, or 5 minutes, so very inconsistently...

Question: How can I make TimeSheet entity load Project via @OneToOne, or do I need to change the design, and load Projects manually?

Comment: One of us isn't understanding the other. If you want a TimeSheet to be associated to a Project, then you *must* set the Project on the TimeSheet (or vice versa) in the transaction where you save the TimeSheet.

Comment: Ryan, your suggestion resolved the issue! Thank you for a quick response! However, I have a question: does setting the Project prior to persisting it, cause an update of the Project record? Is there an annotation that I should use to avoid such an update?

Comment: I can't exactly answer that because I don't know your project. Changes made to your object model inside a transaction are made persistent in whatever way you've mapped the objects to the database. That's what transactions are for. If you don't want changes to be persisted, then don't make changes to your model. It's that simple.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the cascade policy correctly.

```
@OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-cascade

Cascade policy dictates what to do with associated entities when you perform a persistence action on the parent entity.

Comment: As I mentioned, I use Eclipselink 2.3, but assuming Hibernate behaves the same, how should I read the sequence of CasadeTypes above? Assuming that I only want to persist the parent entity, and ONLY LOAD the child entity during a subsequent select, as part of a new transaction, how should your example change? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan points out, you need to maintain the reference in TimeSheet to the Project.  This is because the TimeSheet is cached.  So you can either set the relationship by reading in the existing project when creating the TimeSheet, or by refreshing the TimeSheet after the transaction commits so that it gets built.

The code you have shown sets the TimeSheet->Project relationship fields are read only and doesn't show how the foriegn keys are populated.  Make sure that these are actually set when inserting the TimeSheet through other mappings or it maybe that the TimeSheet legitimately doesn't have a Project - though the fields seem to have a not-null constraint.

Comment: Thank you Chris! I figured the "caching" part and was trying to mitigate it with "@Cache(expiry=-1)" annotation, which does not work in the scenario where parent record is persisted.

Question: how would I refresh it after the commit?

Also, what is the benefit of setting the foreign keys and could you provide an example? As a note, I never intended to insert a "Project" when "TimeSheet" is inserted.

Thanks you Chris!